# Implement oauth2 for springboot API with no login credentials

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, spring-boot-oauth2.1

We have a service that is written in spring boot and currently uses kerberos/spnego with keytab to authenticate.
I was trying to replace this with Oauth2 framework and since there is no UI for the API and it is mostly service Id to be authenticated, I am in a dilemma to how to proceed. I read somewhere that I can use JWT. Should I make use of JWT to get the access token? Can someone please show me a direction? Or there any sample examples that I can follow?

Thanks,

pbale

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a typical case for OAuth2 client-credentials flow (no user).

The easiest option is probably using `client-id` and `client-secret` but both Keycloak and Spring Security support other options.

Add `spring-boot-stater-client` to your dependencies and then [open the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html#oauth2-client-access-protected-resources).

Note that you have a choice of REST clients in Spring: RestTemplate (but in maintenance mode), WebClient (better adapted to reactive apos), @FeignClient (from Spring Cloud), RestClient (not quite mature yet), etc. Each having its own integration with the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` to get access tokens. So open the doc of the one you choose, too.